# Dropped Calls on BCM450

Tags: nortel

Hello we are using the following Nortel Phone System:

Model: BCM450
System sw version: 9.0.1.74.682

Lately we have noticed that the calls are being intermittently dropped. We also use another Phone System called Avaya and that one has no issues, so network here is not the problem.... I dont have much experience with this phone system, can anyone point where to start troubleshooting this problem?

Thank You

Comment: I'd start with the vendor's support.

Comment: Should I accept your answer as problem solved? lol
If I had Vendor support, then trust me, I would not post this question here...

Comment: Are the calls that are dropped internal or external?